# I cannot access jsfiddle.net

Tags: networking, dns, domain, hostname, pppoe

I cannot access jsfiddle.net. My internet connection is PPPOE.

I get a 502 error.

Firefox says:

```
[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "jsfiddle.net" failed. This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.
```

I cannot ping or tracert jsfiddle.net from command prompt. I get the error:

```
Unable to resolve target system name jsfiddle.net.
```

I can ping or tracert the ip of the website (162.243.204.190), and the tracert returns this:

```
Tracing route to 162.243.204.190 over a maximum of 30 hops

1 3 ms 3 ms 3 ms 192-168-0-1.rdsnet.ro [192.168.0.1]
2 6 ms 7 ms 7 ms 10.0.0.1
3 13 ms 15 ms 15 ms cr01.timisoara.rdsnet.ro [213.154.124.132]
4 16 ms 19 ms 19 ms 213-154-124-119.rdsnet.ro [213.154.124.119]
5 18 ms 19 ms 19 ms 213-154-124-119.rdsnet.ro [213.154.124.119]
6 47 ms 47 ms 47 ms 83.217.233.9
7 132 ms 131 ms 131 ms ae-6.r02.frnkge04.de.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.62]
8 82 ms 39 ms 35 ms ae-4.r21.frnkge03.de.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.4.53]
9 131 ms 131 ms 127 ms ae-3.r23.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.3.180]
10 119 ms 119 ms 119 ms ae-1.r06.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net [129.250.4.149]
11 126 ms 125 ms 129 ms xe-0-4-0-10.r06.nycmny01.us.ce.gin.ntt.net [129.250.204.106]
12 116 ms 123 ms 119 ms 192.241.164.254
13 122 ms 123 ms 123 ms 162.243.204.190

Trace complete.
```

So it's a hostname resolution problem. Any ideas of how to fix this?

**EDIT:** This happens for all the devices (computers/smartphones) in my home network. I even tried to plug the internet cable directly in my computer and laptop. The problem still exists.
I can, however, access jsfiddle.net from my mobile data internet connection. Do you think it is an ISP issue?

**EDIT 2:** I contacted the ISP and they send someone with a laptop for testing. Connecting through my router they could not access jsfiddle.net, but when connecting directly through cable, into their laptop, they could access it. Any ideas of what may be wrong with my router/home pc?

**EDIT 3:** I tried to access jsfiddle.net through Tor Browser, as @Haplo suggested and **I succeeded**. Now, can anyone tell me why does it work through Tor Browser? I did not change any other computer or router settings.

**EDIT 4:** So ... I tried to connect the cable directly into my desktop PC to try and manually change the DNS servers used by the connection and I saw that I could access jsfiddle.net. And, at first, I thought that it was because I changed the DNS servers to Google's, but then I connected the cable into the router and I could still access it (and not because of cache). Then I also reverted the changes to the DNS servers and I could still access jsfiddle.net. So it started working for no aparent reason.

**SOLVED!** But I don't know how. It just started to work. Maybe a divine miracle happened. Praise God! :)

Comment: It seems like a router issue. You should state your router model. Also, do you have a chance to try with another router?

Comment: My router is TP-LINK Archer C2. But I tried to connect the cable directly into my desktop PC, and into my laptop, but I still cannot access jsfiddle.net. Same problem. It's so strange ... As a matter of fact I have another router. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried with a NETGEAR WNR2000 router. Same problem ...

Comment: which version of firefox you are using try with chrome.

Comment: @ali786 I tried different browsers. It's not a browser issue ... If you read my question you can see that I cannot ping or tracert the site.

Comment: @MariusStanescu Try Resetting your router. and reconfigure it

Comment: You have mentioned in edit1: 'I even tried to plug the internet cable directly in my computer. The problem still exists.'    But then in edit2: 'but when connecting directly through cable, they could access it.' There is a contradiction.

Comment: There's no contradiction. I plugged the cable into my computer and into my laptop and I could not access jsfiddle.net, but the ISP guy plugged the cable into HIS laptop and it worked from his laptop - I could access jsfiddle.net, ping it, tracert it (only when the cable was plugged in directly; it didn't work when connecting through the router). So, by cable directly, it worked on his laptop, but not on my desktop or laptop.

Comment: Try with TOR Browser and see if you can reach the site with it. If you can't, try with other router.

Answer (score 1):

To look into this issue further, one good way to see what the DNS server is returning is to use `nslookup`. Try running `nslookup jsfiddle.net` and seeing what that returns. There should be both the IP it resolves to along with the DNS server that it contacted to get the information.

If it times out, there is an issue contacting the DNS server, filtered DNS requests(?). Further, try manually changing your DNS servers, without using the Smart DNS Changer tool. This would help to remove the possibility of incorrectly changed DNS settings.

Another thing to do is to check your `hosts` file or firewall settings to verify that there isn't any network filter blocking your requests.

And, to answer your edited question, the reason a TOR browser would function correctly is the way that requests are handled, through a proxy that would also resolve its own DNS requests.

Comment: @marius I want to add this: Since the technician could not access site via router, i'd say change your router while trying above solutions.

Comment: @Haplo As he reported, the issue was persistent across both routers that he tried. I have a feeling this issue is specific to his machine.

Comment: He also stated that he can't access the site with any device on his network.

Comment: Oh, yes, I missed that statement. But, my post still applies, he shouldn't need to replace his router(s) in order for a fix to be found. Rather, it would be good to figure out the issue in his existing setup. This truly sounds like a DNS issue, either improperly configured (Smart DNS, etc. not working) or some other filter that prevents it from accessing certain sites.

Comment: As i understand the situation, his computer ***and*** his router is problematic and should be tested separately in order to solve the problem.

Comment: The nslookup returns DNS request timed out. I already checked the hosts file and I deactivated the firewall. I changed the router DNS servers to Google's (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4). It still doesn't work. I will try through direct cable later this evening.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using fiddler. But you have closed it and not removed it proxy. Please disable its proxy.
Goto "Internet Options">"Connections" Tab>"LAN Settings">Untick "Use a Proxy..."

Or you might have configured Fiddler's upstream proxy incorrectly [Chain Fiddler to an Upstream Proxy](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ChainToUpstreamProxy).

Comment: I unchecked the "Use a Proxy server for your LAN" setting, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Are you able to access other sites?

Comment: Yes. jsfiddle is the only site I cannot access.

Comment: I discovered another site that I cannot access: www.juicebox.net.

Comment: Try changing your dns to google's or opendns [How to Switch to OpenDNS or Google DNS to Speed Up Web Browsing](http://www.howtogeek.com/164981/how-to-switch-to-opendns-or-google-dns-to-speed-up-web-browsing/)

Comment: I used Smart DNS Changer to switch to different dns servers. I also changed my MAC address. But no luck, the problem is still there ...

Comment: What DNS server does Smart DNS Changer use? May be that be might be the problem. Really try changing your dns to google's or opendns.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but a simple google search would have told you what servers [Smart DNS Changer](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/downloads/3329931/smart-dns-changer-320/) uses (Comodo, Google, Norton, Norton ConnectSafe, OpenDNS, Yandex). I tried OpenDNS, and Google's, and Norton, etc ...

Comment: I use OpenDNS and have the same problem. There seems to be a history of OpenDNS blocking jsFiddle (https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/205)

Comment: OpenDNS does allow to whitelist domains, though, and this seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a resolving problem, I have the same resolve, and can access the page.
The problem might be on the 7Layer or on your browsers. Check proxy settings, firewall on you pc and on your gateway.

Tor browser is a browser with a proxy configuration included. all the traffic that pass over it is encrypted and all it wants to get through your network and firewalls is an ip connection and 443 port opened. It doesn't use your dns configuration either.

```
Pinging jsfiddle.net [162.243.204.190] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 162.243.204.190: bytes=32 time=135ms TTL=50
Reply from 162.243.204.190: bytes=32 time=134ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 162.243.204.190:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 134ms, Maximum = 135ms, Average = 134ms
```